# valid_ipn_received.connect never be called django-paypal

Tags: python, django, paypal

I develop by Django and PayPal system

Django 1.6 and PayPal 0.2

I use django-paypal plugin

PayPal has IPN and PDT.
I use IPN

it is about IPN
https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/standard/ipn.html

valid_ipn_received.connect use Django's signal

But, my method never be called in spite of I connected signal in urls.py

https://github.com/shinriyo/paypal_test/blob/master/paypal_test/urls.py#L36

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'paypal_test.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'', include('blogs.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)


from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received
from blogs.models import PurchaseHistory


def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'show_me_the_money called'
    p = PurchaseHistory(name='test')
    p.save()

    ipn_obj = sender
    if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
        print 'payment_status is ST_PP_COMPLETED'
        # Undertake some action depending upon `ipn_obj`.
        p = PurchaseHistory(name='ST_PP_COMPLETED')
        p.save()
        #if ipn_obj.custom == "Upgrade all users!":
        #    Users.objects.update(paid=True)
    #else:
    #    #...

valid_ipn_received.connect(show_me_the_money)
```

Print function never be run.

Could you tell me how to connect?
Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to this site. It would be better to include your code in the question, rather than linking to GitHub. What have you tried so far to debug the call to the print function?

Comment: Payment status is completed.

Comment: I should have set my PayPal setting.

Comment: And, `@csrf_exempt
def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):`

Comment: And `"notify_url": url + reverse('paypal-ipn'),`